# Still need an answer. Calling popToRootViewController after FBSession is open

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

### I STILL NEED AN ANSWER

I have the view controller where facebook login button was added. I have class: FacebookAuth  with method:

```
- (void) performAuth {

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self fbSessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];

}
```

In my facebook view controller I have the IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)performFBLogin:(id)sender {
    FacebookAuth *fbAuth = [[FacebookAuth alloc] init];
    [fbAuth performAuth];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The question is: how to call `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` after `performAuth` is performed. 
According to the official guide there is a callback in the AppDelegate:

```
// During the Facebook login flow, your app passes control to the Facebook iOS app or Facebook in a mobile browser.
// After authentication, your app will be called back with the session information.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i'm note sure but Have you try this way,

```
- (void) performAuth {

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self fbSessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     }];

}
```

Comment: This method is not inside the UIViewController subclass, so doesn't have [self.navigationController] property